# Установка правильных ACL на glusterfs vfs в samba

Tags: windows, samba, cluster, acl

Всем привет. Есть два сервера на самбе. Сделаны шары на glusterfs. samba работает через ctdb. Если подключить шару vfs модулем glusterfs_vfs, тогда на корень из Windows не устанавливаются нужные ACL. На папках действует жествое наследование.
Если примонтированный glusterfs диск сделать шарой в самбе, то ACL ставятся на корень без проблем.
Есть ли способ решить эту проблему? То есть устанавливать нормальные ACL через vfs модуль.

Чтоб было более понятно, конфиги.
/etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[global]
  security = ads
  clustering = yes
  vfs objects = acl_xattr
  map acl inherit = yes
  store dos attributes = yes

[gluster-samba]                                            
  vfs objects = glusterfs                                  
  glusterfs:volfile_server = nt-50.npc-mka.ru              
  glusterfs:volume = samba                                 
  glusterfs:logfile = /var/log/samba/glusterfs-samba.%M.log
  glusterfs:loglevel = 10
  kernel share modes = No
  path = /
  read only = No
  writeable = Yes

[samba]
  path = /media/samba
  read only = No
  public = No
  writable = Yes
```

На gluster-samba как раз и надо рулить ACL.
samba примонтирован в систему:

```
nt-50:/samba on /media/samba type fuse.glusterfs (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,max_read=131072)
```

Так вот если на Windows подключиться к этому серверу, и зайти в обшие папки, то на samba права безопасности выставляются без проблем и сохраняются.
А на gluster-samba ставятся без проблем, но не сохраняются. Хотя на отдельные папки права ставятся, но только r, rw, rwx, то есть доп. атрибуты не сохраняются.